# How can I zero pad part of a loaded image with Numpy / Keras?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am loading an image with:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
```

What I want to do is keep the dimension (224 x 224) but pad it. Where as normally, I'd have an image like this:

[image]

Instead, I want an image like:

[image]

(black border added for clarification. Not something I actually want)

What I want is for the image to be shifted (by some `x` and `y`) and for the rest to be zeroes.

Comment: something like `x=np.ones((224,224,3));x[x_start:,y_start:]=image.img_to_array[x_start:,y_start:]`? This is assuming the image is normalized, else just multiply it by 255

Comment: Can you post ad an answer and then I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is to create an empty matrix and fill the parts you want with the image:

```
x=np.ones((224,224,3),dtype=int)*255
x[x_start:,y_start:]=image.img_to_array[x_start:,y_start:]
```

Notice that you can change the `dtype` to `uint8` if you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in numpy for padding matrices. You should specify padding value for each dimension.

```
np.pad(img, ((top_pad, bottom_pad), (left_pad, right_pad), (0, 0)), mode='constant', constant_values=0)
```

If you need an implementation take a look at [this](https://ai-pool.com/d/padding-images-with-numpy)